# How to draw a button over a last visible uitableview cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I need to display search button at the edge of last visible cell in uiTableView. Something like this:
[image]

I don't know how to get the right CGRect to draw this button (view) and how to redraw this, when the user scrolls the tableview.

Tnx.

Comment: That looks like its part of the uiview, not part of the uitableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way would be to have the button attached to the View (rather than cell), On tapping the button you could find the NSIndexPath for last cell by iterating through visibleCells.

Comment: But visible cells would also contain partially visible cells, where you would need to double check by invoking the method I describe.

Answer (score 1):

The UITableView method

```
- (CGRect)rectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

should help you.

You may need to offset this by the `tableview.frame.origin` if you are drawing it in the parent view.

Hope this helps!